# Best way to get a value from this list of dicts?

Tags: python

I am a little rusty on my python and trying to figure out the best way of getting
I am getting tag info from AWS and need to get the value of the Owner tag, but not sure the best way to get this value.  This is example output from my lambda code

```
[{'Key': 'Budget', 'Value': '000000'},
 {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'NAME'},
 {'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': 'Owner Name'},
 {'Key': 'Private DNS', 'Value': 'DNS'},
 {'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'PROJECT_Name'}]
```

Comment: so essentially you want owner name?

Comment: In other words it's unclear what you consider the value of the Owner tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a list of dictionaries. Therefore, you want to find the dictionary that you actually want (which is the one with `Key: Owner`).

To do that, you can either just loop through the list, or if it is always in the same `index`, access it by it's index. Then retrieve the `Value` of that dictionary item.

```py
list =  [{'Key': 'Budget', 'Value': '000000'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'NAME'}, {'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': 'Owner Name'}, {'Key': 'Private DNS', 'Value': 'DNS'}, {'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'PROJECT_Name'}]

for item in list:
    if item['Key'] == 'Owner':
        print(item['Value'])
```

Answer (score 2):

For more human readable data format you can convert list of Tags in AWS format to JSON or dict:

```
aws_tags = [
{'Key': 'Budget', 'Value': '000000'}, 
{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'NAME'}, 
{'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': 'Owner Name'}, 
{'Key': 'Private DNS', 'Value': 'DNS'}, 
{'Key': 'Project', 'Value': 'PROJECT_Name'}]

aws_tags_dict = {tag["Key"]: tag["Value"] for tag in aws_tags}

print(aws_tags_dict)
{'Budget': '000000',
 'Name': 'NAME',
 'Owner': 'Owner Name',
 'Private DNS': 'DNS',
 'Project': 'PROJECT_Name'}
```

Please keep in mind that duplicate keys in list will overwrite each other in our new dict.

After that getting desired value from dict is pretty straight forward :)